# SQL Delete Method removes all rows in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, sql-delete

Having trouble writing a delete method for android contentprovider SQLdatabase. All rows are being deleted. I want only the row in which I long click to be removed from database and listview. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
    @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long arg3) {
            boolean result=false;
            String query="Select * FROM " + PropertiesContract.CONTENT_URI +"WHERE "+ PropertiesContract._ID
                    + "= 1";
            Cursor c=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(PropertiesContract.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String SELECTION=PropertiesContract._ID + "=?";
                String[]args={""};
                args[0]=String.valueOf(position);
                getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(PropertiesContract.CONTENT_URI, SELECTION, args);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "WHERE CLAUSE= "+SELECTION+" Args= "+args, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                result=true;
            }
            c.close();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Log.d` or something on `query` ?

Comment: Use: `DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = SomeValue` - if MyField is a TEXT field, it then becomes: `DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = 'SomeValue'`